# Angular 2 Populate select drop down values from Mongoose DB

Tags: node.js, mongoose, angular2-forms

I need to fetch the select drop down list vales from Mongo DB mongoose.

In my angular 2 i have something which is static as:

**UPDATED CODE:**

I want to achieve something like this  and I have tried like :

```
<form role="form">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label>Select Category</label><br/><br/>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedObject" name="first" class="form-control">

                //Static data
                <!--<option>Select</option>
                <option>Juices</option>
                <option>Chats</option>
                <option>Meals</option>-->

                <option *ngFor="let c of categories" 
                        [value]="c"
                        [selected]="c.categoryName == selectedObject.categoryName"
                        >
                        {{c.categoryName}}
                </option>
         </select>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

In my component.ts i have something like:

```
export class BlankPageComponent implements OnInit {


selectedObject = null;
categories = [];

constructor(private addproductService: AddproductService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const categories = {
    category_name: this.category_name
 }

this.addproductService.loadData(categories).subscribe(data => { 

});
```

**\src\app\shared\services\addproduct.service.ts**

```
export class AddproductService {

    categories: any;

    loadData(pList: any) {
    this.categories = pList;
    if (this.categories.length > 0) {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://10.22.*.*:3000/categories/get', this.categories, { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
      //this.selectedObject = this.categories[0];
    }
 }
```

> **Error as of now**:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

But i need to get the values of the drop down from backend(bind them)

In my mongoose backend i have a document with field name : category_name which has values like :  Juice, Meals, Chats etc and in postman i fetch them like using API:

> **http://10.22.*.*:3000/categories/get**

I am able to fetch the category from nodejs using GET request,
But how to bind the select control and populate data from mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ts

```
categories = ['Juices', 'Chats', 'Meals'];
selectedCategory: string;
```

.html

```
<form role="form">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label>Select Category</label><br/><br/>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" class="form-control">
                <option disabled>--Select--</option>
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
         </select>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin, i found that , but how do i get the values from backend, via API, as specified in my question

Comment: Have updated my question @Martin, which i need to achieve something as shown , but im unsure of subscribe and flatMap operator, need help!